# $X \sim Exp(\frac{1}{3}) $ If $Y= \max(X,2)$ Find $E(Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics

$X \sim Exp(\frac{1}{3}) $

If $Y= \max(X,2)$ Find $E(Y)$

I did in two ways can anyone point out my mistake ?

First one

$f(y)=
\begin{cases}
\ 2,  & \text{if $0<x\le2$ } \\[2ex]
X, & \text{if $2<x<\infty$ }
\end{cases}$

$E(Y)=E(Y|0<x<2)P(0<x\le2)+E(Y|2<x<\infty)P(2<x<\infty)$

$E(Y)=2(1-e^{\frac{2}{3}})+e^{\frac{-2}{3}}\int \dfrac{x}{3}e^{-\frac{x}{3}} dx=2(1-e^{\frac{2}{3}})+\dfrac{e^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{3}\bigg(\bigg(-3xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}\bigg)_{2}^{\infty}-\bigg(9e^{-\frac{x}{3}}\bigg)_{2}^{\infty}\bigg)=2-2e^{\frac{-2}{3}}+\dfrac{e^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{3}\bigg(\bigg(6e^{-\frac{2}{3}}\bigg)+\bigg(9e^{-\frac{2}{3}}\bigg)\bigg)=2-2e^{-\frac{2}{3}}+5e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$

Second way

$E(Y)=\int \max(X,2)f(x)dx=\int_0^{2} 2f(x)dx+\int _{2}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=2(1-e^{\frac{-2}{3}})+\bigg(\bigg(-3xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}\bigg)_{2}^{\infty}-\bigg(9e^{-\frac{x}{3}}\bigg)_{2}^{\infty}\bigg)=2-2^{-\frac{2}{3}}+5e^{-\frac{2}{3}}=2+3e^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

Now I am not sure which of them is correct and why can anyone tell me ?

Comment: You meant find $E[Y]$, right?

Comment: @keen-ameteur yes I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first method, you are using the law of total expectation, namely $E(Y)=E\,[E(Y\mid X)]$.

Note that

\begin{align}
E(Y)&=E(Y\mid X\le 2)P(X\le 2)+E(Y\mid X>2)P(X>2)
\\&=E(2\mid X\le 2)P(X\le 2)+E(X\mid X>2)P(X>2)
\\&=2P(X\le 2)+E(X\mathbf1_{X>2})\tag{1}
\end{align}

In the second approach, you are using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem to calculate 
expected value of any function of $X$ directly. I would suggest using this method here.

\begin{align}
E(\max(X,2))&=\frac{1}{3}\int \max(x,2)e^{-x/3}\mathbf1_{x>0}\,dx
\\&=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^2 e^{-x/3}\,dx+\frac{1}{3}\int_2^\infty xe^{-x/3}\,dx\tag{2}
\end{align}

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are saying the same thing of course.

Integrating by parts the second integral, indeed we get $E(Y)=2+3e^{-2/3}$

Comment: I did solve it by parts. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @Damandeep Your final answer is correct.

Comment: Can you tell me in first method what went wrong?  I am not able to find mistake. I solved it two three times. There is something wrong .

Comment: @Damandeep I don't follow what you did, but you should end up with the same integration in both methods.

Comment: @Damandeep If you want, in the first method you can use the memoryless property of exponential distribution to say that $E(X\mid X>2)=2+E(X)=2+3=5$. That gives you the answer quickly in fact.

Comment: help me out here $E(Y|2<x<\infty)P(2<x<\infty)=(2+E(Y))(P(X>2))=5(e^{-\frac{2}{3}})$ But I am getting $5(e^{-\frac{4}{3}})$ Just help me pointing out my mistake. in calculating $E(Y)$ when $x>2$. Without memory less i am getting different there is a mistake.

Comment: @Damandeep $$E(Y\mid X>2)=E(X\mid X>2)=\int xf_{X\mid X>2}\,dx=\frac{1}{P(X>2)}\int_2^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx$$, and you know how to evaluate that last integral.

Comment: oh yes, I calculated it carelessly didn't apply the proper definition of conditional expectation. Thanks, man. That was it!

Comment: Bhai  how was your exam? Chat room creat kr ek baat krni thi regarding jam.

Comment: Disappointing in the sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would proceed (similar to your second method):

$E(Y)=\int_0^22\times\frac{1}{3}e^{\frac{-x}{3}}dx + \int_2^\infty x\times\frac{1}{3}e^{\frac{-x}{3}}dx$

$=2(1-e^{\frac{-2}{3}}) +3\int_\frac{2}{3}^\infty t\times e^{-t}dt$

$=2(1-e^{\frac{-2}{3}}) +3\Gamma(2,\frac{2}{3})$

$=2+3e^{\frac{-2}{3}}$

Here is an easy tutorial to solve the incomplete Gamma Integral http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html